# \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt} with negative extra height?

Tags: tables, color

Is there a way to convince the array package to vertically squeeze, rather than expand rows?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
     Time & Money & Length \\
\midrule
\rowcolor{yellow} Contemporary \\
    Sec  &  \$ & inch\\  
    Hour  & cents  & cm \\  
    \midrule
\rowcolor{yellow} Ancient \\
    ?  &  Dinar & Yard \\  
    horae  &   Drachma & Palm \\  
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

My output is:

[image]

And I am trying to get the yellow rectangle touch the `\midrule` above it,
*without* making the line higher than necessary.

** EDIT **

Note that the problem is gone when I use `\hline`, but then, I really like the professional look of `\midrule`, and I would rather not imitate it myself.

Comment: Are you sure it is a problem of `array` and not `booktabs`?

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}`

Comment: Your question is rather strange really. The only difference between `\toprule`, `\midline`  and `\hline` is that the booktab rules add the vertical space that you say you do not want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can in firs step remove vertical spaces around rules determined by the package `booktabs`and than in second step adding vertical spaces to cells using package `cellspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, cellspace}
\setlength\abovetopsep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{Slll}
\toprule
     Time & Money & Length \\
\midrule
\rowcolor{yellow} Contemporary \\
    Sec  &  \$ & inch\\
    Hour  & cents  & cm \\
    \midrule
\rowcolor{yellow} Ancient \\
    ?  &  Dinar & Yard \\
    horae  &   Drachma & Palm \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}% distance below booktabs rules (not \bottomrule)
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}% distance above booktabs rules (not \toprule)
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
     Time & Money & Length \\
\midrule
\rowcolor{yellow} Contemporary \\
    Sec  &  \$ & inch\\  
    Hour  & cents  & cm \\  
    \midrule
\rowcolor{yellow} Ancient \\
    ?  &  Dinar & Yard \\  
    horae  &   Drachma & Palm \\  
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But note that this is completely against the `booktabs` philosophy! So you could also use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\firsthline
     Time & Money & Length \\
\hline
\rowcolor{yellow} Contemporary \\
    Sec  &  \$ & inch\\  
    Hour  & cents  & cm \\  
    \hline
\rowcolor{yellow} Ancient \\
    ?  &  Dinar & Yard \\  
    horae  &   Drachma & Palm \\  
    \lasthline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\specialrule`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\yellowbox}[1]{%
  \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
  \hspace*{-\tabcolsep}%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \colorbox{yellow}{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\strut #1\hspace{\tabcolsep}}%
  \endgroup
  \hspace*{-\tabcolsep}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
     Time & Money & Length \\
\yellowbox{Contemporary} \\
    Sec  &  \$ & inch \\
    Hour  & cents  & cm \\
\yellowbox{Ancient} \\
    ?  &  Dinar & Yard \\
    horae  &   Drachma & Palm \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
     Time & Money & Length \\
\midrule
\emph{Contemporary} \\
    Sec  &  \$ & inch \\
    Hour  & cents  & cm \\
\midrule
\emph{Ancient} \\
    ?  &  Dinar & Yard \\
    horae  &   Drachma & Palm \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I've provided two copies of the table, the latter with what I'd much prefer.

[image]